# How to randomely display images when the activity starts

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to display images randomly when my activity starts. I am using the following code to execute it.

```
final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);

        final String str = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(2);
        img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                getResourceID(str, "drawable", getApplicationContext())));
    }

    protected final static int getResourceID(final String resName,
            final String resType, final Context ctx) {
        final int ResourceID = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName,
                resType, ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
        if (ResourceID == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "No resource string found with name " + resName);
        } else {
            return ResourceID;
        }

    }
```

PROBLEM: This code only randomly generates first two images present in my drawable, whereas i have a total of 8 images.

Thanks in advance.

P.S the name of my images are img_0 , img_1, img_2, img_3, img_4, img_5, img_6, img_7

Comment: final String str = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(8)  <-- insert the number of images you have here

Answer (score 0):

1. Use HashMap to store your image names associated with a key ,

   ```
   HashMap<Integer, String> meMap=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
   meMap.put(0,"img_0"); // add other images as 1, 2, 3
   ```
2. Use Random class to generate number including  0 and less than 8

   ```
   Random rnd = new Random();
   int value = rnd.nextInt(8);
   ```
3. Get the relevant map object according to the generated key(random integer) and      get the respective image name and load it.